# What is the purpose of the branch in front of the beast?

Tags: lev-grossman, the-magicians

"The beast" has a branch obscuring its face. At the end of the book, it removes the branch, and it's revealed that it's

> Martin from the fillory books.

But the thing is, it has to tell them that, since no one knows what it looks like anyway. Why was it wearing this branch?

Comment: [Security through obscurity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Qy4EIvvVj4) perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## For fear of being recognized

Perhaps he thought that people outside Fillory might have some knowledge of who he is.  He actually says after his reveal,

> "Nothing?  You don't recognize me?"

He at least though it likely someone would recognize him.  Quintin actually works it out, but I think logically rather than recognizing the person.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it represented a magical mechanic similar to that used by tanuki and [Kitsune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitsune) to transform or disguise themselves. Here "the beast" wants to hide his true nature and power since he has no idea what is going on to start with.